# How can I test for environment variables being set in Transact SQL?

Tags: powershell, t-sql, variables

I want to write a query for SQL Server that optionally tests against an environment variable.  I invoke my query from PowerShell with something like

```
$sqlVariables = "MY_VAR='something'"
Invoke-Sqlcmd ... -InputFile myQuery.sql -Variable $sqlVariables `
```

And `myQuery.sql` has a clause like:

```
WHERE sometable.somefield = $(MY_VAR)
```

But I can't run this query in SQL Server Management Studio because the variable isn't set.  If I declare a variable in the SQL I can do something like:

```
WHERE (@MY_VAR IS NOT NULL AND somefield.somefield = @MY_VAR)
```

Is there some way to test if `$(MY_VAR)` exists so I can put a test in the first half of a `WHERE` clause and skip comparison if it is not?  I've Googled all over and not found anything close.

Comment: In short: no. `sqlcmd` (and `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, which is just a thin wrapper) require variables to be defined. My advice: since `sqlcmd` variables are dumb syntactic interpolations, just don't use them in favor of PowerShell's own (unless they are required for compatibility with `sqlcmd` scripts). You can still declare T-SQL variables (as in, actual ones) for use in the queries (`declare @myvar nvarchar(100) = $myvar`), and in fact this is a good idea as opposed to using either kind of variable directly.

Comment: For editing purposes, in Management Studio there is another option: you can specify template values of the form `<myvar, nvarchar(50), myvar>` and fill these in interactively with Ctrl-Shift-M (Query -> Specify Values for Template Parameters). These are not variables of any kind and they only work in Management Studio, but as long as you're generating queries programmatically they can be a more convenient alternative.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert.  I guess I'm missing something.  When I try to use the first example, Management Studio complains "Invalid pseudocolumn "$myvar" so that doesn't seem to be enough for interactive use.  I also don't know how to set `$myvar` from PS but that's a different problem.

Comment: PowerShell's string interpolation means that `$myvar` will be replaced  in a string (e.g. `$myvar = 3; echo "this is myvar: $myvar"`). This will not work in Management Studio, of course, which only supports `sqlcmd` variables or templates. The fact that T-SQL variables use `$(var)` syntax, which resembles PowerShell's `$var`, is a coincidence. If you absolutely need interactive use in Management Studio, you will not be able to get around defining the variables. You can put an explicit `:setvar MY_VAR` in the script, but be aware that this overrides any value passed in externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to not have to edit the complex query to remove or modify the handling of the PowerShell variable when testing the query interactively.  What I ended up doing was adding at the top of the file:

```
DECLARE @MY_VAR AS VARCHAR(25) = NULL;

-- Comment out for interactive use
SET @MY_VAR = $(MY_VAR);
```

Then in the body of the query I include a clause in the `WHERE` like:

```
AND (@MY_VAR IS NULL OR sometable.somefield = @MY_VAR)
```

This way I can open the `.sql` file in Management Studio and make a quick, safe change in the first few lines and run the query.